# echo variable livewire component

Tags: laravel-7

i have a livewire component. inside `livewire:option-data` component i create a variable. my question is how to get this variable out and echo into the view outside the component

views/home.blade.php

```
<livewire:option-data variablethatIwant/>
```

Controllers/Livewire/OptionData.php

```
public function updatedSelectedData($selectedData){
$this->variablethatIwant = $somethingselectquerysql->isian;
}
```

in same views
views/home.blade.php

```
echo $variablethatIwant; //this is what i expected
```